# Yii Framework | Nested arrays in same table

Tags: php, arrays, yii, frameworks

Using CActiveRecord my table looks like this:

A column parent_id has relation many to id, and it works properly.

```
id | parent_id
---+----------
1    1      <- top
2    1      <- means parent_id with 1 has parent with id=1
3    1
4    2      <- parent for is id=2
5    2
6    2      and so many nested levels....
```

A goal is how to properly get nested as PHP classically way nested arrays data (arrays inside arrays).
    array(1,1) {
        array(2,1) {
           array(4,2) ....
        }
    }

Problem is Yii. I didn't find properly way how to pick up a data as nested array using properly CActiveRecord.

What is best way to make nested array results? A main goal is to easy forward to render view so I don't separate with too many functions and calling many models outside from modules or models.

A good is one function  to get a result.

Comment: there is a nested set extension for Yii 1.1 and Yii 2 .

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/nestedsetbehavior/ ?

Comment: Is there someone tried  useful example on nested levels with same table?

Comment: @Marin Sagovac, please post all your depending GII generated models, ill help you out.

Comment: A simple is, you have 1 table with parent_id column and relation to id. A top level from lowest ID. A some example is good.

Comment: Iam sure, this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587341/recursive-function-to-generate-multidimensional-array-from-database-result Cheers!

Comment: Yes, I think this is good guide. Exactly for extracting data. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using this: [Recursive function to generate multidimensional array from database result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587341/recursive-function-to-generate-multidimensional-array-from-database-result)

You need get a data as arrays from model:

```
$somemodel = MyModel::model()->findAll();
```

Then put all in array rather then Yii objects model or what you need:

```
foreach ($somemodel as $k => $v)
{
   $arrays[$k] = array('id' => $v->id, 'parent_id' => $v->parent_id, 'somedata' => 'Your data');
}
```

Then call a function:

```
function buildTree(array $elements, $parentId = 0) {
    $branch = array();

    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        if ($element['parent_id'] == $parentId) {
            $children = buildTree($elements, $element['id']);
            if ($children) {
                $element['children'] = $children;
            }
            $branch[] = $element;
        }
    }

    return $branch;
}
```

Then call put all `$arrays` data into buildTree function to rebuild nesting arrays data.

```
$tree = buildTree($arrays);
```

Now your `$tree` is nested arrays data.

Note: there aren't depth into function but in convient way you can add using like this sample: [Create nested list from Multidimensional Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771708/create-nested-list-from-multidimensional-array)